# About Borel set. For continuous $f$, does $\{E|f(E)\text{ is Borel}\}$ form a σ-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets

I want to prove that a continuous function maps Borel sets to Borel sets.
Royden's Real Analysis divided it into three questions:

1. Show that a strictly increasing function that is defined on an interval has a continuous inverse.
2. Let $f$ be a continuous function and $B$ be a Borel set. Show that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set. (Show that the collection of sets $E$ for which $f^{-1}(E)$ is Borel is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets.)
3. Show that a continuous strictly increasing function that is defined on an interval maps Borel sets to Borel sets

But I wonder whether $G=\{E|f(E)\text{ is Borel}\}$ itself form a $\sigma$-algebra? I have tried like this.
Suppose $E_1,E_2,\cdots\in G$. It can be  verified that $f(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}f(E_i)$ is Borel. So $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i\in G$. Also, $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i\in G$ and $E^c\in G$.
If $\mathcal{O}$ is open, then $f(\mathcal{O})$ is open.So $G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets?

If it is correct, things seem to be more simple. But I haven't find any wrong with it. If something goes wrong, is there a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: It need not form a $\sigma$-algebra, and seldom does (for interesting spaces at least). The problem is that, in general, $f(E)^c\neq (f(E))^c$.

Comment: I note it. Can I do it like this? Suppose $f$ is of range $D$. Then $D$ is an open set. And $f(E^c)=f(E)^c\cap D$ is still a Borel set.

Comment: For a continuous strictly increasing function your argument is correct and $\{E: f(E) \, \,\text is Borel \}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra.